# Mapping JAXB Annotated Classes to CSV (or to generic format)

Tags: java, xml, csv, jaxb

I've got a certain number of JAXB annotated classes, generated from some DTD, which allow me to transform objects to xml and xml to objects in quite authomatic way.
These xml are sent to some remote services given to us by some suppliers. Then other xmls are received back and parsed into our domain objects.

The applicative process is something like that

- Process Domain Objects
- Map them to JAXB Objects
- Translate them to xml using the jaxb marshaller.

The inverse flow, which translates XML files received to JAXB Objects and then to domain objects is analogous.

The mapping between domain objects and JAXB objects is not authomatic: fields and structure are different. So there's some logic in it.

Now a supplier asked us to provide CSV files instead of XML files. That is a problem because we don't want to duplicate the mapping logic. So we'd like to reuse the JAXB objects (and possibly their annotations).

We would like also to avoid to make a 2 steps process, like generating xml and then translating it to CSV, if possible (and so for the inverse process).

Is there a way to 'automatically' map the objects to CSV using the JAXB Objects (i.e. the JAXB annotations ) ? To be clearer, the top would be being able to mantain the names of the xml tags into the csv columns.

Otherwise how can we solve this is a someway elegant way ?

NB. I know how to map java classes to csv columns. What i mean for 'elegant' is without rewriting new Mapping classes or, possibly, without having to change the data mapping. For exampe with ObjectMapper in Jackson-dqataformat-text is possible to have data conversion, but in that case i must use java objects field names and not mapped fields used in xml

Thanks for support

Answer (score 1):

it is not a possible. JAXB (Jakarta XML Binding) facilitate to mapping between xml and java. it allows to convert java object into xml and xml to java object. hence, cannot use this framework for convert java object to CSV. [for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html)

but some another framework support to your requirement, convert java object to csv. opencsv is a best library for work with csv in java.[for more info](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

following example is related with opencsv.

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private int id;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private String name;
    
    public Person(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

convert list of person to csv

```
try {
    FileWriter writer = new  FileWriter("output.csv");
  
    List<Person> listPerson = new ArrayList<Person>();
    listPerson.add(new Person(1, "Test One"));
    listPerson.add(new Person(2, "Test Two"));
  
    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy mappingStrategy=  new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
    mappingStrategy.setType(Person.class);
  
    StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Person> builder= new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer);
    StatefulBeanToCsv beanWriter =  builder.withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy).build();
  
    beanWriter.write(listPerson);
    writer.close();
            
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

output,

```
1, Test One
2, Test Two
```

add the following dependencies into your project,

- opencsv
- commons-beanutils
- commons-collections
- commons-lang3
- commons-logging

Comment: I know it, A good solution as also using Jackson dataformat text. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text . I wanted to reuse jaxb annotations because they descrive the same name fields. In this way either i have to compile annotations for each class (and they are a lot) either i send/receive data mapped with java fields name i.e. changing my contract . That's why i'm asking. But its important to m to have a 'final' answer to this topic. It seems answer is NOT, but i wait a little